# Is there a standard rule for $\arctan$ substitutions?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration

I have seen many integrals which make use of the $\operatorname{arctan}$ property of integration i.e. $\int\frac{dx}{a^2+x^2}=\frac{1}{a}\operatorname{arctan}\frac{x}{a}+c$ but I have also seen in many examples that there is some kind of substitution that leads to this kind of format. I am giving an example which will clearly explain my question.

Integrate $$\int\frac{dx}{a^2\operatorname{sin}^2x+b^2\operatorname{cos}^2x}$$

Solution: Rewriting this as
$$\int\frac{dx}{a^2\frac{\operatorname{tan}^2x}{\operatorname{sec}^2x}+b^2\frac{1}{\operatorname{sec}^2x}}$$
$$=\int \frac{\operatorname{sec}^2x \:\:dx}{a^2\operatorname{tan}^2x+b^2}$$
Now let $u=\operatorname{tan}x$ therefore our integral becomes $$\int\frac{du}{a^2u^2+b^2}$$
Now let $v=\frac{au}{b}$. Now our integral becomes $$\int\frac{b\:\:dv}{a(b^2v^2+b^2)}$$
$$=\frac{1}{ab}\int\frac{1}{v^2+1}dv$$ $$=\frac{\operatorname{arctan}v}{ab}+c$$
Now it's just putting back values.

My question is how one determines the substitution $v=\frac{au}{b}$. I have seen this kind of substitution in numerous examples where we have to make an expression whose integral is in the form of $\operatorname{arctan}$.

Since there are standard rules for trigonometric substitutions, I thought that there might be a few for this also. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's by a simple factorization (and experience). We have
\begin{align}
\int\frac{du}{a^2u^2+b^2}&=\int\frac{du}{b^2\left(1+\left(\frac{au}{b}\right)^2\right)}
\end{align}
This immediately suggests the substitution $v=\frac{au}{b}$, so that we end up with something proportional to $\int\frac{dv}{1+v^2}=\arctan(v)+C$.

The way one recognizes that an $\arctan$ is lurking around this is that you must have something of the form
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{
(\text{positive multiple})(\text{variable})^2+\text{positive number}}
\end{align}
in the integrand. If this is the case, then you can call these positive numbers $a^2$ and $b^2$ for some $a,b>0$, so the above factorization will be possible.